# Can clustered ejabberd nodes work without DNS setup or SRV record changes?

Tags: ejabberd

Is there a concept of master slave ejabberd nodes clustering, so that clients always connects to master nodes, and master nodes being intelligent enough to share loads with slave nodes? This would obviate the modf of SRV record or DNS server setup.

Or SRV record modf is must for clustered ejabberd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no master node. A client can connect to any node.